# Django template to Vue component

Tags: django, vue.js, jinja2

So I need to turn some of my templates to Vue components but I am currently using server-side rendering with Jinja how can I turn Jinja render into Vue? I am new to Vue.js so I apologies if that is a terrible question.

Comment: Jinja is a templating engine and isn't really something you can swap out with Vue (a component-based, reactive single page application framework) in an obvious 1:1 manner. Are you planning on running Vue server-side or using it on the front end? Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Hey, I want to run Vue on frontend and I am not the one that wants to do it. It is required in work for some reason(they actually want all the frontend code written in Vue) and I am normally a backend engineer. The UI was so simple so I though I could do it but I had that problem.

Comment: So it sounds like you're converting a server-rendered templated app to a SPA. That's a pretty big change -- basically, instead of forms and separately-rendered pages delivered by the server, you'll be offering something like a JSON API on the back end and hitting these routes using AJAX requests from the Vue app. It sounds like you're going from one app to two, effectively; the back-end API and the front-end SPA. Good luck!